# Not executing the code inside the while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from os import path
import csv
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from pathlib import Path
import time as t    
html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    sp500_raw = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

    spsymbol =[]

for row in sp500_raw.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    spsymbols = row.findAll('td')[0].text.strip()
    spsymbol.append(spsymbols)

df = pd.DataFrame(spsymbol, columns=['Stock_name'])
# df = df.set_index('Stock name')




df.Stock_name.str.replace('^\d+ +','').to_csv('SP Scrapped data.csv', index=False, header=False)
stock_data = []
with open('SP Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    row_count = row_count = sum(1 for row in stockticker_data)
    counter = 0
    while counter < =row_count:                 #Question regarding the while loop
        for i in range(20):
            print(row_count)
            for row in stockticker_data:        #No data is being passed to the variable row
                all_data = []
                for ticker in row:
                    stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '1/1/2008', '1/1/2019'))
                    for df in stock_data:
                        df.to_csv(ticker, header=None, index=None,columns=['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], sep=' ')
            counter = counter +1
        print('sleep')
        t.sleep(10)
```

My question is regarding the while loop. What i am trying to accomplish is for the while loop to run for 20 iterations and then go to sleep for 10 seconds. But for some reason the output is just the row count and then it sleeps and does not seem to execute the for loop after the print statement.

Comment: use print statements to debug this and print the contents things like `print(row)` before the line `for ticker in row:` because maybe the loop doesnt happen cause there is no data to iterate over in row

Comment: @ChrisDoyle You are right but the code works without the while statement and if range, not sure what happened

Comment: `while counter < =row_count:` seems like a mistake while copy pasting since it wouldn't run, but just saying it should be corrected to `<=`. I know it's a small thing, just wanted to point it out. Also, `t.sleep(10))` shouldn't have the extra bracket and the indentation seems to be messed up after the `df.Stock_name.str.replace` statement.

Comment: @Axiumin_I have fixed that, could you please elaborate why would `while counter <=row_count:` not run?

Comment: `<=` would run, but `counter < =row_count` would not run as the interpreter would take that as `<` and `=row_count`, resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what `the code works without the while statement and if range` means? Did you use specific indexes instead of looping through?

Comment: @Axiumin_`stock_data = []
with open('SP Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in stockticker_data:
#         print(row)
        all_data = []
        for ticker in row:
            stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '1/1/2008', '1/1/2019'))
            for df in stock_data:
                df.to_csv(ticker, header=None, index=None,columns=['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], sep=' ')` This works, which is without the counter

Comment: Could you add it to the question so it could be read easier and would help other people?

Comment: @Axiumin_I have added it to the main question

Comment: Thanks! Also, `row_count = row_count = sum(1 for row in stockticker_data)` seems to be the problem. Since it runs once, that means that `row_count = 1`. Since they're also no errors, it seems to be that. Is there only one row in your document?

Comment: @Axiumin_I did check that and `row_count` just gets the number of lines in `stockticker_data`. When i run this code separately it gives me 505 which is the right number! So it is 1 for every row and a sum of all that